# Does a [Functionality] tag make sense?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have seen a few questions that are around the functionality, or feature that may or may not exists. Some of these, such as [Is there a way to "undo" in Windows Phone?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/422/is-there-a-way-to-undo-in-windows-phone), are tagged with something that almost fits - but not quite.

Does a [functionality](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functionality) tag makes sense to use in these situations? If not, what would you suggest questions like the one above be tagged under?

Answer (score 2):

Joe, the undo question was mine and I like your [functionality](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functionality) tag better than [keyboard](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) which is what I plumped for.

Answer (score 0):

Going forward this might start to overlap a lot with OS tags? For example, would you tag a copy & paste question as [functionality](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functionality) or [7.5-mango](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.5-mango) or both?

Comment: right now, the OS tag doesn't make sense. the excerpt says to use it for mango specific stuff, but per http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-can-we-avoid-people-using-the-wp7-5-mango-tag, not many people are left per-Mango and the non-mango marketplace is closing. I think we should scratch the OS tag until it makes sense to have one. Apollo maybe? That is still a year out

Comment: Yes and I pretty much agree. But in a years time will functionality still make sense? I think the func. tag is fine, just trying to play devil's advocate.

Comment: Im not sold on that. IMO that argument pivots on whether or not wp7 becomes a fragmented market like Android. I don't think the OS tag is going to be needed. Now, with the Nokia partnership, we MAY need to differentiate between Nokia phones, and other phones, but as of yet that isn't true.

Comment: Fragmentation may not be that far away. The Nokia 610 has only 256 MB of RAM and that causes some limitations.